# React - Axios data does not render the data once fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, render, axios

So I have a React component which is running an Axios request, the result is set to my 'ist' state property and then checked on the render.

My problem is that because it is an async request, the first render check runs into the `return <p>Loading...</p>;`

I'm looking for a way for my component to render the Loading until the aync request has complete and then render the results.

Here is my code:

```
// defealts
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import axios from 'axios';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageName: 'Home',
      list: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.test();
  }

  test = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/vqqml')
    .then((response) => {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(response);
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
      this.setState({ list: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(error);
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.list.data) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.list.data.name}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Any help or advice is appreciated - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't render because `this.state.list` does not have a `data` property, it has `name`, `age`, and `car` properties.

Your API call response is:

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}
```

and not

```
{"data":{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create another property in `state` called `loaded` and set it to `true` if you get a response. `this.setState({ list: response.data, loaded: true });`

And then ask in your `render`:

`if(this.state.loaded) {...}`

You got to provide your `response` in order to check if `data` property is even in it. You might have confused the `axios` `response.data` with something else like @AndyGaskell already mentioned